# TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to float

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm working on my python script to work out the duration times between start date and end date format like `20140520160000` and `20140520170000` so I can get the hour.

I'm having a trouble with this code:

```
if epgDuration >= 0.10 and epgDuration <= 0.30:
   epgwidth = "250"
```

I get an error when I'm trying to compare the range of the times between 0.10 mins and 0.30 mins.

The error I get is: TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to float.

The error are jumping on this line:

```
if epgDuration >= 0.10 and epgDuration <= 0.30:
```

Here is the results:

```
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 2:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 3:00:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 1:00:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 1:00:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
14:44:55 T:1580  NOTICE: 0:30:00
```

Here is the code when I use to duration the times:

```
for row in programs:
    program_startdate = str(row[2])
    program_endDate = str(row[3])

    try:
       start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(program_startdate, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
       end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(program_endDate, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    except TypeError:
       start_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(program_startdate, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
       end_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(program_endDate, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))

    #workout the duration times to get the program time
    epgDuration = end_date - start_date

    if epgDuration >= 0.10 and epgDuration <= 0.30:
       epgwidth = "250"

    elif epgDuration >= 1.00 and epgDuration <= 1.29:
         epgwidth = "500"
    print epgwidth
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by 0.10 mins and 0.30 mins here? I think you really mean 10 minutes and 30 minutes here, not 6 and 18 seconds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes you are correct. Can you help me how I can use `print epgwidth` outside of the if statements??

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect what I think you are trying to achieve instead. It help if you updated your question with such details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot compare a `timedelta` to a float value.

You *can* convert the object to seconds:

```
if 600 <= epgDuration.total_seconds() <= 1800:
```

where 10 minutes is 600 seconds, and 30 minutes is 1800.

Or create new `timedelta()` objects to compare against:

```
epgwidth = "0"

if timedelta(minutes=10) <= epgDuration <= timedelta(minutes=30):
    epgwidth = "250"

elif timedelta(hours=1) <= epgDuration <= timedelta(hours=1.5):
    epgwidth = "500"
```

I've given `epgwidth` a default value before the `if` statements for the case where the time difference is not falling in the 10-30 minutes or 1-1.5 hour ranges.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have got a problem with print epgwidth outside of the if statement. I get an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'epgwidth' referenced before assignment`. I want to get the variable outside of the if statement to print epgwidth.

Comment: @user3757279: then neither range matched; you'll need to return a default value for `epgwidth` in that case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? i want to print the epgwidth outside of if statement, so how i can fix that?

Comment: Your `epgDuration` value fits neither range; perhaps it is 0.5 minute long for example. In that case *no `epgwidth` is set*. Either add more cases or assign a default value before the `if`statements.

Comment: well i want to check if epgDuration value is between 1.00 and 1.30 then set the epgwidth value. Can you help me to fix the error that I'm getting to allow me to print epgwidth outside of the if statements?

Comment: No everything is working fine, but i just cant post a new question again :(

Comment: @user3757279: did you follow the help center instructions? You do need to improve your question quality generally; your question wasn't overly clear and a bit on the basic side.

Comment: @user3757279: I've given you an upvote because the downvote may not have been entirely deserved, at least you included code and an error message.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me one more upvote so i will give that guy a downvote and i will give you a upvote. Thank you! :)

Comment: @user3757279: sorry, I cannot do that. Nor can you downvote before you reached 125 points.

Answer (score 1):

To get number-of-minutes from a `timedetla` object, you can use `total_seconds()` and divide by 60:

```
epgDurationMin = epgDuration.total_seconds()/60.
if 0.10 <= epgDurationMin <= 0.30:
   ...
```

Also note you can use python's cool [comparison-chaining](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) (e.g. `a <= b <= c`)

Comment: i have try it but it is not working. Bad answer there!