# How to compare current time to times on phpmyadmin

Tags: python-2.7, phpmyadmin

I posted 2 pictures that contains, the code, and the error. How do i solve this and compare the current time and the time on the database?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714670/typeerror-cant-compare-datetime-timedelta-to-float

Comment: @AgamBanga which ones do i convert, the one i got from the database or derp? and how do i do it?

Comment: there are two approaches:- one is what you are currently doing. In this case, you need to convert both object to seconds & compare it. Another Approach is if you have `datetime` field in `uclass` table . simple query will suffice to get the results

Comment: @AgamBanga the one I'm currently doing doesnt work if I use > or < on the argument, however = works fine. If I opted to change the format of `time` into `datetime`, how do i compare it from the one i got from `derp`(just the time)?

Answer (score 0):

What i found that works for my problem is to convert the time i got from row[4] into `str()` which i found from:
[Python format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string)

[image]